# Load JavaScript after page is fully rendered

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I've added JavaScript code to my Drupal 7 theme, but it fail to run as it's expected because css are not properly applied when my function is fired.
So I've tried a minimal implementation to check what's happening.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         alert("Start");  

    }
```

`alert()` is fired before the page is fully loaded (i.e. all titles are missing).
How can I prevent this?

Comment: This question does not seem related to Drupal.

Comment: It is related to Drupal. It's a Drupal site, JQuery is part of Drupal core since 6.x, and this is about Drupal behaviors.

Comment: The question is clearly related to Drupal and the Drupal way to handle the "page is loaded" event is not the usual jQuery way (see amateur barista's answer). Please, move it back to Drupal Answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order execute a script after everything has fully loaded you want:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

jQuery.ready() executes as soon as the DOM is ready, which is usually before external resources have loaded.

Comment: The "Drupal way" of doing this is using Drupal behaviors, this example is a bad practice. Please read the behaviors section in http://drupal.org/node/756722.

Comment: I'm using Drupal behaviors (that's why I submitted this question on Drupal Stack Exchange), but actually my problem was effectively related to the missing window load.

Comment: Don't 1) use $ without wrapping it in an outer context, 2) use jQuery(window).load(...) but Drupal.behaviors. See links in amateur barista's answer.

Comment: @mongolito404 could you explain what you mean by 1? Is it to do with avoiding namespace collisions?

Comment: Yes, it is to avoid namespace collisions. In Drupal 7, jQuery is initialized in compatibility mode so $ is not the jQuery object, see http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility. All of this is documented at http://drupal.org/node/756722.

Comment: @ amateur barista Drupal.behaviors is equivalent to jQuery.ready(), so it does not solve the problem. There is no drupal equivalent for $(window).load().

Comment: @ amateur barista yes I know, I mean they are equivalent as to when they execute in the page load process. If you take a look at Drupal.js you will see that the first line of code in jQuery.ready() is a loop that executes all Drupal.behaviors. They are pretty much the same thing except Drupal.behaviors has the *context* parameter to run DOM queries against.

Comment: I have a form with ajax elements. When the form parts are replaced (actually the whole form), code in my behavior runs BEFORE all the page elements are present.

I'm keen to follow best practice, but using behaviors appears to be incompatible with my situation.

Thoughts?

Comment: After being directed here from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/behaviors-jquery-whats-the-standard-convention-in-drupal-7-for-running-jquery, my comment on the usage of Drupal.behaviors was wrong. If you indeed need to load for all external resource to be loaded, you can't use behaviors since they will be triggered by the document ready event and later DOM modifications. If you indeed need to wait for all external resources to be loaded, then $(window).load() should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Read about the Drupal 7 JavaScript API [here](http://drupal.org/node/756722). You want to give attention to the behaviors section. Behaviors do the same thing you are trying to make in your example, however, when a Drupal page loads, one of the first things it does is instantiate the `Drupal` object. This object gets extended by every module with **behaviors** and **attributes**. When you use Drupal behaviors instead of the standard JQuery on document ready you have accessible in your JavaScript function all the properties and methods defined by other modules.

These tutorials ([1](http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/jquery-js/unlocking-drupal-behavior), [2](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/drupal-theming-jquery-basics-inc-drupal-behaviors)) are for Drupal 6, but they give you a good explanation and idea of what Drupal behaviors are.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to run JavaScript once external resources (here CSS) are loaded. Behaviors does not help here. Since the OP also use jQuery(document).ready as example of non-working code, this answer is still relevant.